# After Upgrading my Razor project to .Net 6 getting @namespace is reserved keyword error in my Razorpage

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, razor-pages

I have upgraded my Razor project to .netStandard2.1 to .net 6 after my updation I'm getting ""namespace" is a reserved word and cannot be used in implicit expressions.  An explicit expression ("@()") must be used." build error in my _ViewImports.cshtml file.

I tried ading AddRazorSupportForMvc didn't workout

Comment: What did you upgrade your project from? What steps did you take to make the upgrade?

Comment: Just updated the .net sdk version in project file and updated related Microsoft Nuget package (3.1.3 to 6.0.0). Another update same project with .net 6 I can able to build without issue in Visual studio 2019 version but getting this error in Visual studio 2022

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.